# What's the behavior of libpq when hostname resolves to multiple IP addresses?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I have a pg_autofailover cluster monitored by single monitor node, 1 primary node accepting read-write connections, and 2 standby nodes ingesting WAL from the primary to keep up to date.

Currently I publish all 3 IPs to my client apps, using which they form the Postgresql connection string: `postgresql://user:pass@ip1:5432,ip2:5432,ip3:5432/dbname`.
I want the client apps to always connect to current primary node, so I advise them to use `targetServer=primary`.

All this is working fine.

Now I have started using TLS based connections, and need all my postgres nodes to share a hostname and certificate for some unrelated and unavoidable reasons. So basically my DNS server will resolve hostname `my_awesome_hostname` to 3 IP addresses: `ip1,ip2 and ip3`.

My question is,
If I tell my clients to use connection string:
`postgresql://user:pass@my_awesome_hostname:5432/dbname`
Then, at the client side, will libpq keep behaving similar to as it is doing now? Will it try to connect to each ip returned from the DNS record 1 by 1 and establish connection with the primary node?

Comment: Could you try it and see?

Comment: That thing is open source, why don't you just look into it?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That could be the answer to like 90% of questions here.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, I tried it using a psql client CLI. It does connect to primary server. But I wanted to know is that co-incidence, because he way my environment is setup, the first VM that comes up, gets to be the primary, and gets the lowest available IP address, so is listed first in the DNS entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my reading of the source, PostgreSQL will store all the IP addresses in its connection object and will treat them just as if you had specified multiple hosts. By the way, the parameter is called `target_session_attrs`, not `targetServer`.

Comment: That helps very much. Also, just realized from this answer that targetServer is a JDBC parameter, not a Libpq thing. So thanks for that too.